# How do I email CSV files to specific emails?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table (volunteers_2009) that has all the volunteers stored within, then I have a table (venues) that list all the different venues a volunteer could work (volunteers are assigned to one venue each, and that is stored within volunteers_2009.venue_id, which equals venues.id)

The venues table also has a column for emails, each email is for the chairman of each venue.

What I want to do is be able to automatically send each chairman an email with a CSV file of the volunteers table (volunteers_2009), and during that process, I want it to match up volunteers_2009.venue_id with venues.id and send the CSV with only the volunteers assigned to that chairman's venue, so the chairman only receives a CSV of the volunteers that were assigned to their venue.

I would run thru the venues table, start at the beginning, match the venues.id to volunteers_2009.venue_id, then run the CSV export function to pull all the data WHERE venue_id = #, then attach it into the email and the recipient would be venues.chair_email.

I already have a export CSV function, I could just pass it the venue_id to pull the appropriate volunteers, and I have a working email function as well, so I can pass it the attachment and recipient.

Here is a sketch of the theory of the function of functions that would get this done:
[image]

If you see a better way on how to go about this (if you can follow along with my poor hand writing), then please let me know, thanks.

Comment: What are oyu needing to know?

Comment: Sounds like you have a good plan, why not just try it?  If you have a problem with it you can't solve, come back and ask.

Comment: I will need to sketch this one out before I dig in. I'll let you know how it turns out, thank you.

Comment: Is that piece of paper sitting on a wooden table?

Comment: If the wooden table doesn't get you any votes, I don't know what will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the biggest thing your missing (if I'm reading this right) is the emailing part.  Have a look at [Swift Mailer](http://www.swiftmailer.org/wikidocs/v3/tutorials/attachments) for examples of how to do this.

I install this on each new PHP project to support exactly this.

Comment: No matter, I hadn't come across Swift Mailer before and it looks handy - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you add error handling, you appear to have gotten it right. You might want to tack the venue id onto the CSV file name so that you can save a copy of each file (for auditing, or bounces, or if the email system is down, etc).